# Select only the latest records

Tags: sql, sql-server

Does anyone here know this?

```
select distinct
    PRODID as PRODUCT_ID,
    STRCDE as STORECODE,
    PRCPR as Price,
    STDTE as Date
from [DWSTAGE].[PRCPLN]
order by PRODID
```

Example result upon query

```
PRODUCT_ID    | STORECODE    | Price  |   Date
---------------------------------------------------
15707         |  15007       |   11    | 2012-01-03
15707         |  15007       |   13    | 2012-02-03
22102         |  15001       |   12    | 2012-01-02
40377         |  15002       |   13    | 2012-01-04
40377         |  15003       |   14    | 2012-02-03
40377         |  15003       |   15    | 2012-03-01
44775         |  15001       |   16    | 2012-06-01
```

My expected result

```
PRODUCT_ID    | STORECODE    | Price  |   Date
---------------------------------------------------
15707         |  15007       |   13    | 2012-02-03
22102         |  15001       |   12    | 2012-01-02
40377         |  15002       |   13    | 2012-01-04
40377         |  15003       |   15    | 2012-03-01
44775         |  15001       |   16    | 2012-06-01
```

Comment: If the latest records are those with the most recent date, why not `ORDER BY STDTE DESC`?

Comment: Please don't yell (ALL CAPITALS IS YELLING). And only tag a single RDBMS i.e. MySQL **OR** SQL Server not both.

Comment: Whats your starting sample data?

Comment: I already try this, But it has also same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `not exists` as follows:

```
select distinct PRODID as PRODUCT_ID, STRCDE as STORECODE, PRCPR as Price, STDTE as Date
From [DWSTAGE].[PRCPLN] t
Where not exists
(Select 1 from [DWSTAGE].[PRCPLN] tt
 Where tt.PRODID = t.PRODID
   And tt.PRODUCT_ID = t.PRODUCT_ID
   And tt.STDTE > t.STDTE)
order by PRODID
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `With Ties` is the most efficient way and Based on your desired result, `Price` and `Date` should not be part of our partition section :

```
select TOP 1 WITH TIES *
from [DWSTAGE].[PRCPLN]
order by ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PRODID,
    STRCDE
     ORDER BY STDTE desc)
```

Comment: Hi,

thank you for the answer, but @popeye get the right answer for me,
i will soon use this method of yours. ty

Comment: @EfrenCaballes . . . Although this works, it is not the most efficient from a performance perspective.